# Do solenoids embed into Möbius strips?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, continuum-theory

I found a strange attractor which looks a lot like a solenoid. The attractor continuum is the closure of a continuous line which limits onto itself, and it is locally homeomorphic to Cantor set times Reals. It sits in the Möbius strip.

[image]

Does the Dyadic solenoid embed into the Möbius strip?  What about solenoids in general?  Could the strange attractor above actually be a solenoid?

Comment: If it embeds into the Möbius strip, you get a 2-fold covering, that embeds into an oriented strip (cylinder). It seems visually quite clear that it can't (embed into the plane at all), although this certainly requires a little argument.

Comment: IIRC if you follow an interval transversal to the trajectories along the flow, after one turn the interval becomes half-folded, i. e. you get a surjective non-injective self-map of it, two-to one on half of it and one-to-one on the other half. I don't see how could you possible embed such behavior in any 2-manifold... But is your question about this attractor or about a solenoid?

Comment: I guess that one general statement of the form "every compact space that has a locally trivial fibration with quotient the circle and fibre a Cantor set", that embeds as a subset of the plane, is a product (circle)$\times$(Cantor), would settle everything.

Comment: But that statement is false. For example, take the suspension of an irrational rotation of the circle, which gives a foliation of the torus. Then do a Denjoy blowup (split one leaf) to make it a compact space of the type you describe embedded in the torus. @YCor

Comment: I am also pretty sure that every orientable geodesic lamination on a hyperbolic surface is of the type you describe. @YCor

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm not sure that I understand your example (why does it embed in the plane), but I agree that my statement fails. Indeed, for every order-preserving self-homeomorphism of the (standard) Cantor set, the mapping torus obviously embeds into a cylinder. Still I don't see how to embed the mapping torus of a minimal self-homeomorphism of the Cantor set into the plane.

Comment: I missed the signficance of embedding in the plane. In fact none of the geodesic laminations that embed in planar surfaces are orientable (a consequence of the Poincare Hopf theorem for singular foliations) hence none of them fiber over the circle.

Comment: That might point towards a proof of the nonembedding of the dyadic solenoid in the plane: (1) check that its embedded image has the local structure of geodesic lamination (it seems to me there is some significant topology to do here); (2) check that this implies it *is* a geodesic lamination; (3) apply the Poincare Hopf theorem to prove that it is non-orientable, hence a contradiction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No solenoid can be embedded into the Mobius strip. To derive a contradiction, assume that some solenoid $S$ embeds into the Mobius strip $M$. Let $\pi:C\to M$ be a 2-fold covering map of the cylinder $C$ onto the Mobius strip. It is well-known that the solenoid $S$ contains a dense subset $D$ which is the image of the real line under a continuous map $\phi:\mathbb R\to D$ (and this image of $\mathbb R$ is called a *composant* of the solenoid). By the lifting property of the covering map $\pi$, there exists a continuous map $\varphi:\mathbb R\to C$ such that $\pi\circ\varphi=\phi$. Then the closure $K$ of the connected set $\phi(\mathbb R)$ in $C$ is a continuum such that $\pi(K)=\bar D=S$. Taking into account that the cylinder $C$ embeds into the plane, we conclude that $K$ is a planar continuum and hence the solenoid $S$ is a continuous image of a planar continuum.

On the other hand, by a result of Krasinkiewicz in his paper [Mappings onto circle-like continua](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm91/fm9115.pdf), no solenoid is a continuous image of a planar continuum (as solenoids have infinitely divisible first cohomology group whereas the first cohomology group of any planar continuum is finitely divisible). This is a desired contradiction.

Comment: I still do not understand.  I did know that the circle is the only solenoid which embeds into the plane.  But I don't see why this implies the circle is the only one that embeds into the Möbius strip.

Comment: I also don't understand the double cover argument, or at least why it needs no further explanation (since a solenoid is obviously not Peano so doesn't satisfy the lifting criterion).  But shouldn't you be able to take a transverse axis of the Mobius strip whose support on the solenoid $S$ is the Cantor Set, which can then be symmetrized across the axis to build an ad hoc double cover?  Then it would remain to show that this (circle-like) double cover is a solenoid, giving the contradiction.  This seems clear, but requires work, from the classification of solenoids among circle-like continua.

Comment: @ForeverMozart I wrote more explanation in my answer.

Comment: Nice proof!  Thanks!  For those who stumble across this, maybe it should be said that the dense image of $\mathbb{R}$ is just one of the composants.

Comment: @JohnSamples Thank you for the suggestion. I have added a note about composants to my answer.